# Removed files from Xcode are still being used during runtime

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on a iOS app in Xcode 4
Into which I have imported PhoneGap1.0 as a nested Xcode project - with all the sources and files

Now I want to upgrade from PhoneGap1.0 to PhoneGap1.2.

I used drag&drop to import the PhoneGap1.2 Xcode project into my app's project
However, the files used at runtime are the *old* PhoneGap1.0 files - I noticed that by stopping at breakpoints

So how can I make Xcode forget about 1.0 (old) and use only 1.2 (new)?

Thank you so much,
Nur

Answer (score 0):

This may be one of the few questions where cleaning all targets and re-building may actually be the answer. `Product`-->`Clean`. Also, make sure you have removed the older files.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the app from the device usually fixes this for me. It seems that during the installation of the app, it sometimes doesn't overwrite files that are already there.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to do a clean build is usually a useful thing to do too.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Product>Clean or cmd-K. This will rebuild from scratch your product.